# Are blender files compatible with photoshop?

Tags: photorealism

I have been using Photoshop as my primary design vehicle but I am wanting to develop more photo-realistic backgrounds and images to sell to my clients. I have never used a program like Blender. Am I on the right trail learning to use Blender. If yes, are Blender files compatible with Photoshop as I would want to take the finished Blender image into Photoshop to use with layers for final output to customers.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a descriptive title that summarizes the content of your question, avoid words like "Question" since that covers every post here. Also make sure your question is not subjective and wont attract opinion based answers. "*Am I on the right trail*" is not really an answer we can objectively answer

Comment: Hello :). You can use the OpenExr file format. It supports layers and can be imported into PS.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to the community! I have been using blender primarily for Archviz and I can say you are in the right track. rendered files have a JPEG, PNG, BMP and many other file outputs so you can open it in photoshop (I use GIMP) to enhance image.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Please don't add thank you as comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted